# Raspberry Pi NTFS SAMBA SHARE Permission denied Windows 7

Tags: debian, samba, network-shares, ntfs, windows-8

I'm running a little RaspberryPi machine that I wanted to turn into a low power network share that is completely unprotected on my home network, the aim is for it to be a universal 
network dump and media share.

I have got USB drive mounted and read-writable from linux, the share is visible from my Windows8(64Bit) desktop without username or password, but nothing I have on the network including my W7(64Bit) can get read/write access to the share.

```
pi@SambaPi /var/log/samba $ uname -a
Linux SambaPi 3.6.11+ #474 PREEMPT Thu Jun 13 17:14:42 BST 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

fstab:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
/dev/sda1  /media/USBDRIVE  ntfs-3g rw,defaults,acl       0      0
```

cat /etc/samba/smb.conf | egrep -v '^#|^;|^$'
*(Samba config without blanks, comments and those odd semi-colons (What are those lines?) removed)*

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   realm = raspberrypi
   netbios name = raspberrypi
   server string = %h server
   dns proxy = no
   name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 10
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   security = SHARE
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY
   usershare allow guests = yes
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
[USB]
   path = /media/USBDRIVE
   comment = Media Share
   writeable = yes
   browseable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   public = yes
   force user = root
   read only = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0775
   directory mask = 0775
```

getfacl /media/USBDRIVE

```
# file: USBDRIVE/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other::r-x
```

getfacl /media/USBDRIVE/testFileMadeAtCommantLine.txt

```
# file: testFileMadeAtCommantLine.txt
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

I have been through my system logs and I have not seen *anything* that corresponds with the permissions messages I get when I try to add or delete a file to the share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [force user](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#FORCEUSER) setting doesn't mean you don't have to supply a password. From smb.conf:

> This user name only gets used once a connection is established. Thus
>   clients still need to connect as a valid user and supply a valid
>   password. Once connected, all file operations will be performed as the
>   "forced user", no matter what username the client connected as. This
>   can be very useful.

Specify [guest account](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#GUESTACCOUNT) value and give this user rwx permissions.

Also you have `read only = yes` and `read only = no` specified on the same share? Fix that.

You can use [testparm](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/testparm.1.html) command to check smb.conf for errors and print out bare samba configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Janis. Your answer helped me out heaps. And it works just fine. I removed what you recommended, added what you recommneded and changed permissions and ownership to a "guest-like" user. My config now looks like this:

Pi had a usernamed games. chown'd all the files to that user and gave Games all permissions. And changed the config as you recommended.

Now it works great and my config is this:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   realm = raspberrypi
   netbios name = raspberrypi
   server string = %h server
   dns proxy = no
   name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 10
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   security = SHARE
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY
   usershare allow guests = yes
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
[USB]
   path = /media/USBDRIVE
   comment = Media Share
   writeable = yes
   browseable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest account = games
   public = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0775
```